Permission denied when running a mv command as user after entering into sudoers file
I have a user which needs to move a file to a dated folder.
I have an entry into the sudoers file as follows:
backupuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mv /var/lib/pgsql/base_backup/*.tar.gz /var/lib/pgsql/backups/$(date +%Y_%m_%d/)

However the command asks for a password when ran as the user suggesting the command isn't being picked up which i entered in the sudoers file.
Am I missing some escape characters, i've tried escaping using \ infront of (, ), %, but am given a syntax error when I attempt that.
If you need more info please let me know.

Please note that the $() part and the glob (*) are interpreted by the shell before they become parameters for sudo.
Since the arguments are different every time, you should probably create a script that this user is allowed to run as the privileged user.

This is all about evaluation order. When a user executes a command such as this
sudo mv /var/lib/pgsql/base_backup/*.tar.gz /var/lib/pgsql/backups/$(date +%Y_%m_%d/)

The order of evaluation is such that the wildcards and $(…) expansions are processed by the shell before the command is executed. If you had two source files one.tar.gz and two.tar.gz, and today's date was 25 April 2024 you would end up with this command:
sudo mv /var/lib/pgsql/base_backup/one.tar.gz /var/lib/pgsql/base_backup/two.tar.gz /var/lib/pgsql/backups/2024-04-25/

Now although the sudoers file does understand * as a wildcard (but far more liberally than the shell - beware!), the $(…) part is not understood and so will not match except to a literal sequence of 18 characters. The resulting command is therefore rejected by sudo.
You would be better creating a script and having that script executed by your backups user. For example this, placed somewhere that be modified only by root:
#!/bin/sh
# Move backup files to a date-based directory
########################################################################
#
today=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
ss=0

src='/var/lib/pgsql/base_backup'
dst="/var/lib/pgsql/backups/$today"

if [ ! -d "$src" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: Missing source: $src" >&2
    ss=1
fi
if [ ! -d "$dst" ] || [ ! -w "$dst" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: Missing or inaccessible destination: $dst" >&2
    ss=1
fi
if [ "$ss" -gt 0 ]
then
    exit "$ss"
fi

mv -f -- "$src"/*.tar.gz "$dst/"
exit

